# Android Auto : How to get current step count?

Tags: android-auto

There is a Template restriction,
the 5th step must be NavigationTemplate, PaneTemplate or MessageTemplate.

I'd like to know How to get the current total number of steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find how to do it following this link: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#template-restrictions

Here you find a note on how to **Enable debug overlay** and you can find it in your debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the recommendation of having a 1:1 relationship between screen and template type, you can use [ScreenManager::getStackSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/ScreenManager#getStackSize()) to get this count (assuming any updates to a screen meet the [template refresh criteria](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#template-refreshes)). Check out the docs on [Template restrictions](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#template-restrictions) for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that this function is released at 1.1.0-beta01. However, what I mean is about the number of "steps". This shows numbers of Stack but not current total number of steps. Sorry for can not set this be solution.